# prove that if ($x_n$) is a Cauchy sequence then ($x_n^2)$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Tags: real-analysis

(i) prove that if ($x_n$) is a Cauchy sequence, then ($x_n^2)$ is a Cauchy sequence.

(ii) is the converse true? That is, if ($x_n^2)$ is a Cauchy sequence, then ($x_n$) is a Cauchy sequence?

Can anyone help me how to begin solving this question?

Comment: Your last two posts are also problem-statement questions. See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Answer (score 4):

(i): $|x_n^2-x_m^2|=|x_n-x_m| \cdot |x_n+x_m| \le |x_n-x_m|(|x_n|+|x_m|) .$

Now use that $(x_n)$ is bounded.

(ii): look at $x_n:=(-1)^n.$

Comment: thank you so much. I appreciate it